# How do I patch up my weapon?

Tags: weapons, larp, props, prop-maintenance

The other week I caught my larp weapon on a barbed wire fence, and it cut a tiny notch into the face of it. No foam was pulled out but it left a mark.

This is the sword as it appears from the manufacturer:

[image]

How can I fix this sort of damage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a syringe of liquid rubber (latexmilk) inject that straight into the puncture hole, don't screw around with tape, it's crappy looking and unsafe.
 Glue and the like will harden and make sharp edges, so not the best idea.

Latex milk will dry with a slight yellow hue, so add a drop of paint; the paint used on Warhammer figurines gives a very nice colour to the latex. I would usually go for "Boltgun" but in this case I would advise "Platemail & Chainmail"

Mytholon is designed by Germans and Danes, they expect to break their weapons soon (2-3 runs) because they don't hold back their slashes, so they make cheap "disposables"; next time buy a French or English weapon if you want durability.

Usually it is best to strip the latex layer and refurbish, but the spray paint Mytholon uses can't be stripped without damaging the castfoam

Comment: Foam latex gets into every nook and cranny it can and should have a strong hold to patch up. If its only a minor nick though I might let it go and paint it in (battle damage like scars adds character).

Answer (score 3):

If it is only a mark/nick that is the problem, your best bet is probably just to paint over it and let it go.  For larger issues, I defer to prior answers: Duct Tape/Super Glue/Gorilla glue/Epoxy + Raw materials to fill any gaps

Answer (score 2):

I think that some sort of silicone spray is the best thing to use.  A small amount of glue *may* help if the damage is not somewhere that will hit others.  Glue tends to become harder with time and you can end up with a nasty lump in your weapon.  During game, I have seen gaffer tape fix all sorts of things: it is like the force.  It has a dark side, a light side, and it binds the universe together.

Comment: I don't think this is the sort of weapon that ductape will look good on...

Comment: Gaffer tape is a stop gap measure.

Comment: Ok, so after the gaffa tape, then what?

Comment: Glue is effective but I might recommend an epoxy for its resilience.

Comment: @CatLord: glue (whatever the type) can get hard and thus present a hazard which could make the sword unsafe -- Note: **could make** and not **will make**.